# Data Factory/Synapse: How to merge many files?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

After generating ~90 different 100 mb gzip'd CSV files, I want to merge them all into a single file. Using the built-in merge option for a data copy process, it seems that it would take well over a dozen hours to do this operation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yymnW.png

How can I merge many files in blob/ADLS storage quickly with Data Factory/Synapse?

Comment: Why do you need to merge them into a single file? What’s generating the 90 files?

Comment: Many small files is kind of an antipattern for Azure Synapse Analytics, Spark and cloud generally so if you can get more control over that process that would be a good idea.  Having said that, this does seem extraordinarily long.  When looking at performance in dedicated SQL pools (assuming that's what you are using) you should always consider: DWU, resource class (of the loading identity) and concurrency (any clashing operations?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a 2 step process.

1. Merge all files from CSV into a Parquet format.
2. Copy that Parquet file into a CSV file.

Writes into Parquet are generally quick (provided you have clean data like no spaces in column names) and they are smaller in size.

Edit - ADF Data Flow is another option. If that is still not fast enough then you might have to create a Spark Notebook in synapse and write spark code. Use a spark pool size with a balance between time and cost.

Comment: I tried this but found effectively that it is just as slow using the data copy process.

Comment: I see. Have you tried the Data Flow in ADF? I am afraid if that is not fast right enough either then you might have to create a Spark Notebook in synapse and write spark code.

Comment: Good thought about using Spark!

Comment: Have edited the answer. Give this a try and you can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Easy, just convert the objects to a pandas dataframe and then do the merge.

Step #1:

```
df1= df1.select("*").toPandas()
df2= df2.select("*").toPandas()
```

Step #2:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

See this link for more info.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Also, here's another technique to consider.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/merge-multiple-files-in-azure-data-factory

https://markcarrington.dev/2020/11/27/combining-data-with-azure-data-factory/